# BFS in Adj matrix java 2 dimensional

Tags: java, matrix, breadth-first-search

Im trying to calculate BFS but I guess I could not assign the number to the array. it shows the ranking correctly but there is no increase in the scoring part.Output must be " 0 1 2 3 4 5 " , and this is right but there is something wrong .

```
public class BFS_DFS {
    public static int[] BFS (int [][] graph) {
        int[] output = {0};
            int start=0;


            int v=graph.length;//a[][] is adj matrix declared globally
            boolean visited[]=new boolean[v];//indexing done from 1 to n
            LinkedList<Integer> queue=new LinkedList<Integer>();
            visited[start]=true;
            queue.add(start);
            while(queue.size()!=0)
            {
                int x=queue.remove();
                System.out.print(x+" ");
                for(int j=graph.length;j<graph.length;j++){
                    output[j-1]=x;
                }

                for (int i=1; i < v; i++)
                    if((graph[x][i] == 1) && (!visited[i]))
                    {
                        queue.add(i);
                        visited[i]=true;

                    }
            }
    return  output ; }



 public static void main(String[] args) {

        //DO NOT WRITE ANY CODE IN MAIN METHOD
        int [][] graph={{0,1,1,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0,1,1},{1,0,0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,0}};

        int [] BFSresult={0,1,2,3,4,5};
        int [] DFSresult={0,1,4,5,2,3};
        int grade=0;

        if (Arrays.equals(BFS(graph),BFSresult )) {
            System.out.println("BFS is working correctl");
            grade+=50;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("BFS is not working correctly");

        if (Arrays.equals(DFS(graph),DFSresult )) {
            System.out.println("DFS is working correctl");
            grade+=50;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("DFS is not working correctly");

        System.out.println("Your grade is->"+grade);

    }


}
```

Comment: how nice to see so much code below the comment that says not to write any...

Comment: @SharonBenAsher the code in main method was obviously given as such and he had to implement the BFS method..

Comment: oh I see.... sorry

Comment: Somewhat similar : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844011/3992939